# JOIN on three tables is not working

Tags: mysql, php

I have these three tables, `user`, `categories` and `files`

In `users`, table I have a column `user_id`

[image]

And I have this query that shows all Categories.

```
SELECT `categories`.`category_id`, `categories`.`timestamp`,`categories`.`name`,       
LEFT(`categories`.`description`, 50) as `description` ,
COUNT(`files`.`file_id`) as `file_count`
  FROM `categories`
   LEFT JOIN `files`
     ON `categories`.`category_id` = `files`.`category_id` GROUP BY `categories`.`category_id`
```

What I want to do is that to show only categories which are created by specific user.
Adding a `WHERE user.user_id = categories.category_id` gives

```
Unknown column users.user_id
```

Comment: Instead of giving us diagrams, could you please give us SHOW CREATE TABLE files... \G and some DML (INSERT INTO files... VALUES(...) so that we can reconstruct your tables with valid data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't joined the users table so `users.user_id` isn't available. But `user_id` is in the other tables so you could use `files.user_id` or `categories.user_id`.

You will also need to add all columns in the `SELECT` to the `GROUP BY` other than `categories.description`.

You may also want to review your schema design because having `category_id` and `user_id` in each table doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

1. First add your table in a `JOIN` condition
2. Then use a `WHERE` clause like below.

Just modified your query:

```
SELECT `categories`.`category_id`, `categories`.`timestamp`,`categories`.`name`,       
LEFT(`categories`.`description`, 50) as `description` ,
COUNT(`files`.`file_id`) as `file_count`
  FROM `categories`
   LEFT JOIN `files`
    LEFT JOIN  `User`
     WHERE user.user_id = categories.category_id
     AND  `categories`.`category_id` = `files`.`category_id` GROUP BY `categories`.`category_id`
```